# How to set up the environment for the HoneyComb?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have already installed the android sdk for windows. I was working with the Api level 8  and API level 15.

Now I want to work with the Honeycomb for Tablets. But I don't know how to add the honeycomb API Level in my case.

When I am opening the Windows -->  Preferences in eclipse, then I am getting this screen.

[image: preference]

I want to setup the environment for Honycomb. please help me out.

This is my SDK MANAGER SHOWING:

[image: sdk manager]

**This is the Tool menu in SDK Manager in my case.**

[image: Tool in SDK]

Comment: Uncheck the "Installed" check box and then try updating. You might also want to uncheck and then check the "Updates/New" checkbox and see if it fetches the new API's from the repo

Comment: getting messege DOne loading packages.nothing else. API 11 not getting by this method

Comment: Any updates after unchecking and checking the "Updates/New" checkbox?

Comment: help me to come out of this problem guys

Comment: try the new solution in my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: @sultan.of.swing See the updated question. I have added the tools menu option showing in my case. I can see only one option here i.e manage ads on sites and if i select that then it asks for the URL of add on sites. Dont know what exactly it is.

Comment: Hey, can you try clicking on the "Tools->Manage Add on Sites" option and add under "Official Add-On Sites" the list of sites given in the following image:
http://imgur.com/AD7qy

Comment: getting error like this site is already listed

Comment: @sultan.of.swing Its done mate.please now do a favor. please write this in the answer step by step, so that other can solve this issue simply. thanks a lot. I have added the URl of the android system image

Comment: please edit your answer mate with the commented link

Comment: glad to know it worked for you :) I'll update it in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Android SDK Manager

Select API level 11 (Android 3.0) for Honeycomb and click on Install Packages.

If you fail to see any other API levels apart from already installed packages, try this:

Clear your cache and reload. The clear-cache button is in Tools > Options in the SDK Manager, and reloading is Packages > Reload in the SDK Manager.

Link: [SDK Manager doesn't show anything, only already installed packages](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/wp8FFGmsgAQ)

In case you do not see any "Options" in the drop down menu just like the OP, then click on "Tools -> Manage Add On Sites" and see if the list of the repositories are there or not. Just to make sure, ensure that all the repos listed in the following image is present in your repo. If not, then add the missing ones:

[image: List of Official Add On Sites]

Now go to "Packages -> Reload" and see if you can find the rest of the Android API's in the repo.

Comment: This is what I am asking I am not able to see the API level 11 in my SDK manager mate

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Keep sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Start the Android SDK Manager by double-clicking `android.bat` in `D:\Android Java Stuffs\android-sdk\tools\android.bat`.

From there, update to the latest SDK version. As of the time of writing that would be Android 4.2 (API17).

Update all your tools while you're there. :D